# Does "Image File Execution Options" intercept CreateProcess commands?

Tags: winapi

I want to know how the mechanism of debugger injection works. Why is "Image File Execution Options" so special?

I have two guesses.

1. **CreateProcess** will call an internal function that checks against the list of registry keys. If it is found, then it manipulates the arguments and calls the debugger exe instead.
2. There is **some other service** listening for CreateProcess calls and intercepts them. It kills the original call or message (if createprocess is a message or message-like), then it runs the new process as if the original caller called it.

My desire is to verify and update components before an application starts. I like the IFEO "feature" but i need to run the original process after the verification step so I need a way to run  it without recursing into the updater. I hope that by learning more about the injection system I can get this system working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/reiley/archive/2011/07/30/a-debugging-approach-to-ifeo.aspx) explains how it works.

In Windows XP and 2003 the user-mode `CreateProcess` code reads the registry and, if required, launches the debugger instead.

In more recent versions of Windows this functionality has moved into kernel mode.

But neither case seems to involve a general interception mechanism for `CreateProcess`.

Comment: Link seems to have moved to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/reiley/a-debugging-approach-to-ifeo